# Java Eclipse Visitor Not Leaving Main() of test file

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I'm attempting collect all the methods in a Java file using the Eclipse AST package. I believe that I have the CompilationUnit created successfully. However when I attempt to use a visitor to collect the information it doesn't go past the main() method of the file I'm testing.

```
public void parseCode(String fileName) {
    String strSource = "";
    try {
        strSource = codeToString(fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setSource(strSource.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(new NullProgressMonitor());

    SCTVisitor v = new SCTVisitor();
    cu.accept(v);
    System.out.println(v.m);
}

public class SCTVisitor extends ASTVisitor{
    List<SimpleName> m = new ArrayList<SimpleName>();

    SCTVisitor(){
        System.out.println("What is love");
    }

    @Override public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
        this.m.add(node.getName());
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is part of the file I'm using to test:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Cheese");
    countWordsViaGUI();
}


// allow user to pick file to exam via GUI.
// allow multiple picks
public static void countWordsViaGUI() {
    setLookAndFeel();
    try {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Opening GUI to choose file.");
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(getFile());
            Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
            st.start();
            ArrayList<String> words = countWordsWithArrayList(fileScanner);
            st.stop();
            System.out.println("time to count: " + st);
            System.out.print("Enter number of words to display: ");
            int numWordsToShow = Integer.parseInt(key.nextLine());
            showWords(words, numWordsToShow);
            fileScanner.close();
            System.out.print("Perform another count? ");
        } while(key.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y');
        key.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading the data file. Exiting the program." + e);
    }
}
```

My results are:

```
[println, countWordsViaGUI]
```

My expected results are:

```
 [println, countWordsViaGUI, setLookAndFeel, scanner, println, getFile, Scanner, ...]
```

Please let me know if you have any insight into this problem.

Comment: what do you mean by *it doesn't go past the main() method* ?? Also, put expected output and current output to related

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say is that the visitor doesn't visit nodes outside of the main method in the test file. I'm attempting to collect every method used in the file. My output is only showing methods from the main() in the test file while I was expecting the results to include methods used in other parts of the file.

Comment: Took the comments out of the test file and it worked correctly.